# issue while matching special char '\' in regular expression using '\\'

Tags: python, regex

I have very simple python script to match some special characters like -,+,-,.
But Im not getting expected result while using regex \ to match a single '\' char.

```
import re
pat = r'[-+*\\]'
text = 'fdkjdfk\sdsdd'
if re.search(pat,text):
   print re.search(pat,text).group()
else:
   print "not found"
```

On running above code , it prints 'not found'
It seems I am doing some mistake here , any help appreciated !!!

Comment: The above code works for me - it prints `\\`.

Comment: sorry I think I messed up , I was not using raw string it must be 'pat = '[-+*\\\]' without 'r'

Comment: @S.Lott: The text does have a backslash. `len('\s')` produces 2.

Answer (score 2):

`\` is an escape character.

Try escaping it:

```
text = 'fdkjdfk\\sdsdd'
```

Comment: thanks for reply ...
Using text = 'fdkjdfk\\sdsdd' and then pat= r'[-+*\\\]' match it right.

But does it means in my text I have to use(replace '\') char '\\' everywhere instead of '\'.

Comment: I haven't used Python enough to give a definitive answer to the question in your comment, but the docs http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html explain more about escape sequences.

Comment: No, you do not need to use `replace()` -- typing in two backslashes puts one backslash in the string.